# Customise org babel block color

Tags: org-mode, babel

Customise org-babel source block color such that:

1. when the block is folded, the `#+begin_src` line is the default color
2. when the block is open, the `#+begin_src` and `#+end_src` lines are highlighted a different color.

I include many src blocks in my files, which are mostly collapsed, so I would like some highlighting to draw my attention to location of the block that is open.

Answer (score 0):

What if you call `M-x`, `m`, `set-background-color`, `LightYellow`? A cheap trick. However, it may be easier, than tracking down those particular faces and custom changing them in an `org-mode` hook?

Define a key-binding to `set-background-color` or add to your `init.el` file?

---

Try in init.el:

```
 (add-hook 'org-mode-hook
      (lambda () (if (window-system) (progn (custom-set-faces
          '(org-block-begin-line ((t (:underline "#A7A6AA" :foreground "#008ED1" :background "#EAEAFF" :extend t))))
          '(org-block ((t (:background "#EFF0F1" :extend t))))
          '(org-block-end-line ((t (:overline "#A7A6AA" :foreground "#008ED1" :background "#EAEAFF" :extend t))))
) ))
  ))
```

Like the 2nd answer in this SE post.
[orgmode - change code block background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44811679/orgmode-change-code-block-background-color)

Comment: I don't know what the 'm' means in `M-x m set-background-color LightYellow`. If i just use `M-x set-background-color LightYellow` the entire emacs background changes, not just the background of the lines beginning and ending the block.